# Proving that any subspace $U$ containing $U_1\cup U_2$ contains $U_1+U_2$ and that the span of $U_1\cup U_2$ is $U_1+U_2$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $U_1$ and $U_2$ be subspaces of a vector space $V$ and let  $$U_1 + U_2 = \{  \textbf{v}_1 + \textbf{v}_2 : \textbf{v}_1 \in U_1, \textbf{v}_2 \in U_2\} $$
Prove that every subspace $U$ of $V$ containing $U_1 \cup U_2$ contains $U_1 + U_2$. And prove that the subspace spanned by $U_1 \cup U_2$ is $U_1 + U_2$.

I know that $U_1 + U_2$ is the smallest subspace of $V$ containing $U_1 \cup U_2$. Then if take any vector in $U_1$ and vector in $U_2$ then both vectors are in the union $U_1 \cup U_2$ and $U_1 \cup U_2 \subset U$ and since $U$ is a subspace then it is closed under addition and scalar multiplication, thus  $U_1 + U_2$ is also in $U$. Please let me know if it is correct and any help on part 2. Thank you.

Comment: I think it is confusing that you said "I know $U_1+U_2$ is the smallest subspace containing $U_1\cup U_2$. **Then** $\cdots$." Actually "smallest" is vivid but is not formal. But basically in this context, it means that $U_1+U_2$ is the intersection of all subspaces containing $U_1\cup U_2$, i.e. $U_1+U_2=\{x| x\in W, \text{for any subspace} W \text{s.t.} (U_1\cup U_2)\subseteq W \}$. But why you proved this again after the "Then"? What does your "smallest" mean in your post "I know $U_1+U_2$ is the smallest subspace containing $U_1\cup U_2$."?

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track by using the hypothesis that $U$ is a subspace of $V$. But you didn't include the most important part of the proof that shows that $U_1\cup U_2\subset U\implies U_1+U_2\subset U$.

This part includes you letting $u\in U_1$ and $v\in U_2$ and then using the hypothesis that $U_1\cup U_2$ is a subset of $U$ and that $U$ is a subspace to conclude that $u+v\in U$. This then shows that $U_1+U_2\subset U$.

For the second part, use the definition of span to conclude that $\text{span}(U_1\cup U_2)\subset U_1+U_2$. Then use the definition of $U_1+U_2$ to conclude that $U_1+U_2\subset \text{span}(U_1\cup U_2)$. Then by definition of equality of sets, you would have shown that the subspace spanned by $U_1\cup U_2$ is $U_1+U_2$.

Comment: thank you. I appreciate your answer.